Service Bus Processor is not triggering even if there is message in topic
I am using Service Bus Processor to receive messages from a topic subscription.
var topicName = "nf-channel-topic";
var subscriptionName = "nf-channel-subscription";

// Create a Service Bus client
await using (ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(configuration.GetSection("AzureString").Value))
{
    // Create a processor for the subscription
    ServiceBusProcessor processor = client.CreateProcessor(topicName, subscriptionName, new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());

    // Register a message handler and receive messages in a loop
    processor.ProcessMessageAsync += async processMessageEventArgs =>
                {
                    string body = processMessageEventArgs.Message.Body.ToString();
                    SBusMessageRequest mySbMsg = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SBusMessageRequest>(body);
                    
                    //var requestMsg = JsonSerializer.Serialize(body);
                    //Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {body}");

                    // Complete the message
                    await processMessageEventArgs.CompleteMessageAsync(processMessageEventArgs.Message);
                };

    // Register an error handler
    processor.ProcessErrorAsync += args =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString());
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

    // Start processing
    await processor.StartProcessingAsync();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();

    // Stop processing
    await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
}

After sending message to particular topic, this processor should receive the message, but it is not being triggered, if we keep Console.ReadKey();, then it's being triggered, but it is not executing the next methods.

That's the expected behavior. The processor needs to run to receive messages. Console.ReadKey() keeps your process running. You should read up on the SDK and how it works. Otherwise you're learning how to run w/o learning how to walk.

If we keep Console.ReadKey(), then next lines of code are not executing. @SeanFeldman. This line of code is kept in Program.cs in .net core api project. After this above code, this CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(); is there, this line is not executing, So the API is not Building.

Running ServiceBusProcessor requires a continuously executing process. Program.cs is not intended for that as its purpose it to execute the host.
What you should do is using a BackgroundService or implement IHostedService to run the processor, and register your hosted service with your application. See documentation on both types for details.
For example, with IHostedService you could create and start ServiceBusProcessor in StartAsync() and stop it in StopAsync().
